# How to declare [Int] in optional

Tags: arrays, swift, option-type

How to declare [Int] in optional

I try

```
var listofNumber = [Int]?()
```

But it's not working

But if I try

```
var listofNumber : [Int]?
```

The problem is I cant use listofNumber.append anymore

Value of type '[Int]?' has no member 'append'

Comment: To declare an optional array of type int use this: `var listOfNumber: [Int]?` that will declare it but not initialise it. when you need to use it you need to do this: `listOfNumber = [Int]()`

Comment: Are you trying to make an optional array of `Int`s, or an array of optional `Int`s?

Comment: probably `var listOfNumber: [Int]? = [Int]()` or `var listOfNumber: [Int?] = [Int]()` or `var listOfNumber: [Int?]? = [Int]()`, it depends on what you'd lie to achieve here.

Comment: `var listOfNumbers: [Int]? = [Int]()` or `var listOfNumbers: [Int]? = []`

Comment: In practice [T]? is rarely semantically different from and empty [T] so you shouldn't use it unless nil really means something different from empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are writing `[Int]?` but this is just syntactic sugar.

Behind the scenes, what you're actually declaring is`Optional<[Int]>`.

If you look at the documentation for `Optional<T>`, you can see that there are three initialisers declared for this value type:

- `init(from: Decoder) throws` This one is used in conjunction with the coding protocols introduced in Swift 4. It is of no relevance here.
- `init(nilLiteral: ())` This one initialises the `Optional<T>` to `nil`.
- `init(some: T)` This one initialises the `Optional<T>` to `T`.

Your statement `var listOfNumbers = [Int]?()` does not match any of the initialisers and thus is not working.

Now what you probably want to do - and what most of us would presumably do here - is:

`var listOfNumbers: [Int]? = []`

This declares the type of `listOfNumbers` to be `[Int]?` (aka `Optional<[Int]>`) and at the same time sets its initial value to an empty array.

The crucial thing to note here is that virtually all of this is syntactic sugar. If you went out of your way and defined the var "natively", it would look something like this:

`var listOfNumbers = Optional<[Int]>(Array<Int>())`.

(*You could leave out the generic parameter to `Array`, as it would be inferred by the type system here.*)

Since this is cumbersome to write and also doesn't read quite well, you can use the short version.

As for the second issue regarding `Array.append`.
Your var is of type `[Int]?` (aka `Optional<[Int]>`) and thus you cannot access vars or call methods defined on the `Array` type. You need to unwrap the optional first.

`listOfNumbers?.append(4711)`.

If you're using Xcode, it should actually provide you with a fix-it for this kind of issue.

Now since we were talking about "explicitness" anyway:

`listOfNumbers?.append(4711)` is again a shiny example for syntactic sugar.

Explicitly written, it would look something like this:

```
// Optional<T> is actually an enum, so we can switch over it.
switch listOfNumbers {
case .some(var value):
  value.append(4711)
case .none:
  break
}

// Alternative
if case .some(var value) = listOfNumbers {
  value.append(4711)
}
```

As you can see, this is quickly getting bloated, especially considering optional chaining, etc. Hence, the short version was "invented".

I've written this long answer to make it clear to you what's going on behind the scenes here and I guess it never hurts to remind yourself of the nuts and bolts you’re building upon sometimes.

---

#### Update

Note that it would be perfectly valid for you to write the statement like this:

`var listOfNumbers = [Int]?([])`
or
`var listOfNumbers = [Int]?(nilLiteral: ())`

The amount of syntactic sugar you are using it up to you and you can mix it with "explicit" coding however you want.

Answer (score 2):

For declaring use this syntax:

```
var listOfNumber: [Int]? = []
```

Then use any method you need:

```
listOfNumber?.append(20)
listOfNumber?.insert(40, atIndex: 1)

listOfNumber!                               // result: [20,40]
```

Second part.

Here's your code:

```
if listOfNumber?[0] == nil {
    print("if access...")
} else { 
    listOfNumber?.append(20)
    print(listOfNumber!)
}
```

Comment: if(listOfNumber?[0] == nil){
                print("if access")
                    listOfNumber?.append(20)
                print(listOfNumber!)
            } .      and i got this Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Look at second part of my answer!

Comment: sry pls forget about above question , I mean my .append seem not affect with listOfNumber . with this  if(listOfNumber?[0] == nil){
                print("if access") // if access was print
               
                    listOfNumber?.append(Number2) . // not working ??
                print(listOfNumber) // it's still print nil but why?
            }

Comment: Use other construction: " if listOfNumber != nil { ... } "  or  " if listOfNumber!.count > 0 { ... } "

Answer (score 1):

`var listofNumber : [Int]?` is the good approch.

Dont forget to `init` using

`var listofNumber : [Int]? = []` or `var listofNumber : [Int]? = nil`

After, as the array is optional, use `listofNumber?.append(10)`.

Comment: if(listOfNumber?[0] == nil){ print("if access") listOfNumber?.append(20) print(listOfNumber!) } . and i got this Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value any idea ?

Comment: It’s because of your print. Never use ! Operator